# At what level should I be able to engage a Giant?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I kill a giant?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34719/how-do-i-kill-a-giant)

[image: A troll]

I have discovered a Giant. I have attempted several times to kill it without success. Even if I try to block its attacks I usually end up being pummeled into the ground or flung at least 50 metres into the air.

[image: Mid air lolz]

I don't particular want to kite for a long period of time to kill it now, so what level would be appropriate for engaging it?

Are there any weaknesses/tips for engaging?