# Best way of handling giants?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I kill a giant?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34719/how-do-i-kill-a-giant)

What is the best approach to taking down giants in the game?

I am currently level 23, high smithing levels which nets me some great heavy armor, etc.
I'm also quite skilled with single hand, and archery.

Currently what I try is to use the landscape (high places, etc;) and shoot till dead (I make my companion wait out of sight so that they don't engage) the giants.

This sometimes works (if I find good cover, etc), however its annoying and time consuming.  Is killing giants something best left for later levels? Or are they just that hard to kill?  I mean I can take down dragons easily, but Giants get one 'wallop' in on me and I go flying off the map.

I've had success casting Oakskin too, (to some extent, until the 2nd giant killed me -- spell probly wore off)

Comment: Can these questions be merged? I find the other question is too dependent on the fact that the "game is new"

Comment: You might be missing the Heavy armor perks.  Giants don't one-hit-kill you with good armor.

Comment: No I have the Heavy Armor Perk I just get creamed by their clubs.. as mentioned I am level ~20s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've discovered the only strategy that really works at low levels -- preventing the giant from hitting you at all.

Other than using terrain features, there is [another way to do this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Giant):

> Effective ways to combat Giants include frost spells and frost-enchanted weapons. The damage appears to be the same as the other elemental types, yet this will stun them causing them to walk extremely slowly for many seconds.

Giants are [always the same level](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Giant), 32, so you should expect them to be far more difficult than dragons at early levels, and far easier than dragons at later levels.